# Reshaping from a table with multiple options for each value to a wide binary table

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to build a function that takes in a data frame that is populated with a multiple choice question (people can pick multiple options for the same question) and pivot it into a wider binary form. I can do this when only one option is chosen for the column, but not if multiple options are chosen for one user.

An example input:

```
test_data <- data.frame(user_id = c(1,2,3,4),
  col_name = c("1","2, 3, 4" , "5", "2"))

> test_data
  user_id col_name
1       1        1
2       2  2, 3, 4
3       3        5
4       4        2
```

And my desired output:

```
> example_result
  user_id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1       1  1  0  0  0  0
2       2  0  1  1  1  0
3       3  0  0  0  0  0
4       4  0  1  0  0  1
```

I can get it almost into this form by using `dplyr` like so:

```
test_data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col_name", 
              values_from = 'col_name', 
              values_fill = 0,
              values_fn = function(x) 1)
```

but get a result where each unique value becomes a column:

```
  user_id   `1` `2, 3, 4`   `5`   `2`
    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1         0     0     0
2       2     0         1     0     0
3       3     0         0     1     0
4       4     0         0     0     1
```

Any ideas?